# How to manage multiple views and urls in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to add multiple charts in one web page as we do to make dash-boards. I made two views for two charts.

```
**def index(request):
    gapminder = px.data.gapminder()
    plot_div = plot(px.scatter(gapminder.query("year==2007"), x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", size="pop", color="continent",
                     hover_name="country", log_x=True, size_max=90),output_type='div')
    return render(request, "index.html", context={'plot_div': plot_div})

def indexx(request):
    random_x = [100, 2000, 550]
    names = ['A', 'B', 'C']
    plot_div = plot(px.pie(values=random_x, names=names),output_type='div')
    return render(request, "index.html", context={'plot_divv': plot_div})**
```

and two URLs too.

```
**from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('', views.indexx),
]**
```

but in result only one chart is visible, the one which URL is on top. I am a newbie kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Django will run the first view that matches the url, and will ignore the rest. You need to do it all in one view.

```
def plot1():
    gapminder = px.data.gapminder()
    plot_div = plot(px.scatter(gapminder.query("year==2007"), x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", size="pop", color="continent", hover_name="country", log_x=True, size_max=90),output_type='div')
    return plot_div

def plot2():
    random_x = [100, 2000, 550]
    names = ['A', 'B', 'C']
    plot_div = plot(px.pie(values=random_x, names=names), output_type='div')
    return plot_div

def index(request):
    plots = [
        plot1(),
        plot2()
    ]
    return render(request, "index.html", context={"plots": plots})
```

In your template, put your plot code into a loop so it will loop through and display all the plots it gives you.